# php error_get_last() stops the script in case of E_USER_DEPRECATED

Tags: php

tried to search this but still no luck..

I am using Symfony 3.2 and when I launch my app in prod it works fine without showing `E_USER_DEPRECATED` errors (though I know there are some). But when I try to catch all fatal errors and log them to file with this code:

```
register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'handleFatal'));

public function handleFatal()
{
    $error = error_get_last();
    $this->monolog_logger->debug('Error type is: '. $error['type']. ' ' . serialize($error));
}
```

it stops script execution and shows me that some code is deprecated. In case of `E_USER_DEPRECATED` or `E_DEPRECATED` I want only to log this into my file without stopping the script. Also without calling `error_get_last()` the code works fine and does not stop. Any ideas how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved, I got a dummy `var_dump()` which was removed and everything worked fine.